# Call dynamic method without naming parameters

Tags: abap

I'm calling a method of a class dynamically like this, and it works:

```
CALL METHOD (gc_zcl_mapping_methods)=>(<ls_import_params>-attr_logic_method)
  EXPORTING
    iv_dats      = <lv_value>
  RECEIVING
    rv_timestamp = <ls_import_params>-attr_value.
```

The problem is that I'm naming the two parameters `iv_dats` and `rv_timestamp`.
Not every method has these parameter names so I'm looking for a way to call them without naming the parameters.
I tried like this, but I get many syntax errors.

```
<ls_import_params>-attr_value = (gc_zcl_mapping_methods)=>(<ls_import_params>-attr_logic_method)(<lv_value>).
```

Is there a correct syntax for my goal to omit the parameter names?

Comment: Why not to create all possible parameter names and make them optional? Except returning of course, with returning it is impossible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to name the returning parameter and other parameters too.

The full dynamic calling is explained here in the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_parameter_tables.htm)

For your example code, that will give this code :

```
DATA(ptab) = VALUE abap_parmbind_tab( 
    ( name  = 'IV_DATS' 
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>exporting 
      value = REF #( <lv_value> ) )
    ( name  = 'RV_TIMESTAMP'
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>receiving
      value = REF #( <ls_import_params>-attr_value ) ) ). 

DATA(etab) = VALUE abap_excpbind_tab( ).

CALL METHOD (gc_zcl_mapping_methods)=>(<ls_import_params>-attr_logic_method) 
    PARAMETER-TABLE ptab 
    EXCEPTION-TABLE etab.
```

You may get the name of the returning parameter by using RTTI (here, I suppose that the class is global), you may also adapt it to get other parameter names:

```
DATA(rtti_class) = CAST cl_abap_objectdescr( 
    cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( '\CLASS=' && gc_zcl_mapping_methods ) ).

DATA(method) = rtti_class->methods[ name = <ls_import_params>-attr_logic_method ].

DATA(returning_parameter) = method-parameters[ parm_kind = cl_abap_objectdescr=>returning ].

DATA(returning_parameter_name) = returning_parameter-name.
```

I let you add the handling of exceptions.

---

**ADDENDUM : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example** :

Let's say this static call is to be done dynamically :

```
DATA(result) = VALUE sychar01( ).
DATA(ltxttab) = VALUE rslinltab( ( kind = 'E' numb = 1 param = 'MSGID' value = 'MESSAGEGY9' )
                                 ( kind = 'E' numb = 1 param = 'PRAGMA' value = '##DUMMY' ) ).

cl_abap_syntax_message=>long_text_exists(
  EXPORTING
    p_kind            = 'E'
    p_number          = 1
    p_ltxttab         = ltxttab
  RECEIVING
    p_result          = result
  EXCEPTIONS
    message_not_found = 1 ).
```

Dynamic version (also, the RECEIVING parameter is being determined dynamically at runtime, but usually it's not needed because its name is known at compile time) :

```
DATA(rtti_class) = CAST cl_abap_objectdescr(
    cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( '\CLASS=' && 'CL_ABAP_SYNTAX_MESSAGE' ) ).
DATA(method) = rtti_class->methods[ name = 'LONG_TEXT_EXISTS' ].
DATA(returning_parameter) = method-parameters[ parm_kind = cl_abap_objectdescr=>returning ].
DATA(returning_parameter_name) = returning_parameter-name.
ASSERT returning_parameter_name = 'P_RESULT'. " <=== just for the demo

DATA(ptab) = VALUE abap_parmbind_tab(
    ( name  = 'P_KIND'
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>exporting
      value = REF #( 'E' ) )
    ( name  = 'P_NUMBER'
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>exporting
      value = REF #( 1 ) )
    ( name  = 'P_LTXTTAB'
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>exporting
      value = REF #( ltxttab ) )
    ( name  = returning_parameter_name
      kind  = cl_abap_objectdescr=>receiving
      value = REF #( result ) ) ).

DATA(etab) = VALUE abap_excpbind_tab(
    ( name = 'MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND' value = 1 ) ).

CALL METHOD ('CL_ABAP_SYNTAX_MESSAGE')=>('LONG_TEXT_EXISTS')
  PARAMETER-TABLE ptab
  EXCEPTION-TABLE etab.
```